# get new list which contain any numeric value from current list using LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

How to get new list which contain any numeric value from current list using LINQ query in c#. 
??

i.e : 
CurrentList  >> abc, bcd123, abcd, 332bcd

what I want : NewList  >> bcd123, 332bcd

**What i have done in past:**

```
 var newList= videos.Select(x => x.OldList.Contains("1"));
```

Comment: Have you edited question with `OldList` property?

Comment: no sir, @ Sergey Berezovskiy

Comment: OK. Looks like I missed that part. Side note - when you use static method `Regex.IsMatch` then new instance of Regex class is created for each checked string

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for your valuable code, @ Sergey Berezovskiy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if any character in string is number (with help of [`Char.IsNumber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk2b3t2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method):

```
var newList = videos.Where(x => x.OldList.Any(Char.IsNumber));
```

Another option is usage of regular expression:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d");
var newList = videos.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x.OldList));
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. But shouldn't videos.Where(regex.IsMatch);  be videos.Where(x => regex.IsMatch(x))?

Comment: @Ehsan nope, `IsMatch(string)` satisfies `Func<string, bool>` signature, so you can pass it

Comment: @Ehsan you were right, because there is another overload of `IsMatch(string,int)` which makes ambiguous call with `Where(Func<string,int,bool> predicate)`. If you have list of strings, you can use `list.FindAll(regex.IsMatch)` but overloaded Where and IsMatch makes it impossible on IEnumerable

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular expression

```
 var newList= videos.Select(x => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(x.OldList, @"\d"));
```